# Update Dropdown List from Code Behind Using Javascript / JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, code-behind

I have an application with two sections.

The top section has a `dropdownlist` that displays all the members in the `database` using a code behind method on called on `page load`.

The bottom section has a grid where you can `add / delete / edit` members using `JQuery`.
A change in this section obviously does not rebuild the dropdownlist in the top section.

I want to run some code in the `JQuery` success method that `updates/rebuilds` the `dropdownlist` to reflect the newest change to a member.  I would like if possible to use the same code behind method that hits the db on `page_load` to `populate` the dropdown.

Is this possible?  If so, how would I go about accomplishing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**[Requested Code]**
.aspx file

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="director" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList> 
 jQuery success() fired on add/delete/update member grid.
```

.aspx.cs (code behind)

```
private void LoadDirectorOptions(int deptId)  
{
            var memberRepo = new MemberRepository();  
            List<Member> members = memberRepo.GetMembers(deptId);

            director.DataSource = members;
            director.DataTextField = "FullName";
            director.DataValueField = "Id";
            director.DataBind();
            director.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("<Please Select>", "0")); 

}
```

Comment: What about providing your relevant code?

Comment: you'll want use AJAX if you don't want to reload the page

Comment: @Jonesy I know I want to use AJAX.  I am just not sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: @A.Wolff There isn't much to the code, just a page control, code behind method and Jquery success event.  I want to rebuild the page control using the JQuery success event populating it using the code behind method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the same code behind method since it is a server side code and the `JQuery`  code happens on the client side unless you refresh the page after the `JQuery` code executed. You can grape all the members on the same web service you are providing for updating the grid.

down list. for example :

```
  $.ajax({
      // Updating the grid here and retrun all the members : it will be saved in the response
      type: "Get",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      dataType: dataType,
      success: success(data)
    });

    function success(data)
    {
      //here you can get the resposne from the server
      // Iterate through data and add option elements
      $(".members").append("<option value=? text=?/>");

    }
```

Most probably your data must be `JSON` that has all the members in your server members database table. then you can add a `CSS` class(members) to your drop down list and use `JQuery`  selector to select the drop down list.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh the dropdown without refreshing the whole page, you need to wrap them inside an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). When the grid in the bottom section is changed, update the UpdatePanel so that it rebinds the dropdown. To force the UpdatePanel to update in Javascript you could use the [GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx) method to force a postback like this:

```
<%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(updatePanelID, "")%>
```

Comment: Can I update the update panel from Javascript / JQuery?
If so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @nmat Wish I could downgrade you for even suggesting an update panel.Please go to the link I suggested and learn real ajax.

Comment: @Baxter Yes, you can force a postback in javascript and then rebind the dropdown in the pageload. See the updated answer. If you want more detail you need to provide some relevant code of your app

Comment: @idlehands23 The UpdatePanel is compatible with the ASP page cycle so it allows him to reuse the same code from the Page_Load method without doing a full postback in the traditional sense.

Answer (score 1):

Should use ajax in your success call to call method. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I was thinking that control might be the solution.  I am just not sure how to use it to rebuild a page control using a code behind method.  Can you elaborate on this?